# Benefits of rank in clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am playing Clash of Clans and I just recently joined a clan. There was a message that followed telling me that the leader of the clan had promoted me to elder. Is there any benefits of being in a different rank **(for example, is there a better reward for a co-leader than an elder or a member?)**? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being an elder means you have basic privileges over unranked members such that you can invite people from outside and kick unranked members.They however cannot demote people.

Co-leader has the same privileges except that they can kick both unranked members and elders and have the power to demote lower ranks until they are a member (the lowest rank).

They can also promote unranked members and elders up to the co-leader rank.

The leader has the same privileges but can promote/demote/kick out anyone within the clan.

Additionally co-leaders and the leader can change the clan message that is displayed at the front clan page as well as sending clan announcements to the other members within the clan.

so in a sense, ranks give a certain individual a portion of the leader's power. These powers/privileges increase with rank.

As for rewards given to higher members? there is none.

Its all a measure of responsibility within the clan... in a fun way

Answer (score 10):

[image: CoC permissions matrix]

They say a picture is worth 1,000 words, but in this case I just need 30 characters to make a post.

Comment: Co-Leaders can promote Member to Co-Leader.

Answer (score 1):

There are four ranks:

- Member-The current rank you have which means you have no advantage yet your treated equally.
- Elder means you can kick players that are not ranked and you can invite other players to you clan.
- Co-Leader-Can promote members to elder and co-leaders. They can demote elders to members. They can kick elders and members. They also have the advantage of editing the clan description like the war frequency, badge, description, minimum trophies and clan location. They can also invite other players. They also have a special feature to send out a message to all the clan mates for example a warning for being inactive.
- Leaders-Is the highest rank and has all those advantages mentioned and also the extra advantage of demoting a co leader. They have to demote them selves and promote someone else if they want to leave their clan.

Comment: What about war search / selecting participants? Is that available to co-leader or leader only?